# Can I make a code in python that ignores special characters such as commas, spaces, exclamation points, etc?

Tags: python, special-characters, palindrome

I want to create a code that will return "true" (if I type in a palindrome regardless of case or if there are special characters in it), and "false" otherwise. The code I have so far works for phrases with no special characters such as commas, apostrophes, spaces, etc.

```
def is_palindrome(my_str):
    my_str= my_str.casefold()
    rev_str= reversed(my_str)

if list(my_str) == list(rev_str):
   print("True")
else:
   print("False")
```

when I do:

```
 print (is_palindrome("Rats live on no evil star"))
```

it returns True because it is a palindrome

when I do:

```
 print (is_palindrome("Hello World!"))
```

it returns False because it is not a palindrome

when I do:

```
 print (is_palindrome("Madam, I'm Adam"))
```

it returns False. but I want to create a code that considers this a palindrome

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: Why not just remove all unacceptable characters before you test it?

Comment: You need to come up with a rule for what you do and don't want to count. The fact that you're using `casefold` instead of `lower` implies that you might care about non-ASCII letters. For example, if you just skip everything that's not an ASCII letter, `Århus` and `suhr` count as reverses of each other. (You also might want to normalize to combined form before comparing, too.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to filter before testing then:

```
letters = [c.casefold() for c in my_str if c.isalpha()]
```

would pick out only the letters and lowercase them, after which you can test of those letters form a palindrome:

```
return letters == letters[::-1]
```

This works because [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) returns `True` only for letters.

Combined into your function:

```
def is_palindrome(my_str):
    letters = [c.casefold() for c in my_str if c.isalpha()]
    return letters == letters[::-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def is_palindrome(my_str):
...     letters = [c.casefold() for c in my_str if c.isalpha()]
...     return letters == letters[::-1]
... 
>>> is_palindrome("Rats live on no evil star")
True
>>> is_palindrome("Hello World!")
False
>>> is_palindrome("Madam, I'm Adam")
True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_str = my_str.casefold()
my_str = ''.join(e for e in my_str if e.isalpha())
```

This should recreate my_str with only alphabetical characters, using .isalpha(). Then do the test on that. If you want to keep a record of original string, just stored the recreated version is a temporary string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to exclude punctuation and spaces you can use `str.translate`:

```
from string import punctuation

d = {k: None for k in punctuation}
d[" "] = None

def is_palindrome(my_str):
    trans = str.maketrans(d)
    my_str = my_str.translate(trans).casefold()
    return my_str == my_str[::-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may get just alphanumeric character in your string;

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '', your_string).lower()
```

By the way this one works, if you ignores non-ASCII chars.

Comment: But `\W` doesn't mean "alphanumeric", it means "valid as an identifier". It includes `_`, may or may not include non-ASCII letters, and does not include non-ASCII digits.

Comment: I do not say \W means "alphanumeric", but you are right about _.